# In angular material UI (material.angular.io/cdk/tree) , how to select specific value from Tree with flat node in form values?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material, tree, formbuilder

I wanted to select a specific value from tree with flat node using @angular/cdk/tree and after selection, it should come as form value. so that I can store the selected value in database.

In the below link I am trying to develop the logic but I am stuck here. Please help!
**https://material.angular.io/cdk/tree/overview#cdk-tree-nested**

Comment: What are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I am new to angular and I am not able to develop the logic

Comment: I would recommend that you give it a go, and then post a question when you are stuck on something. Then we are much more able to help you. Try the tour of heroes on the angular website that will give you a nice introduction to angular.